# Apostrophe in select with postgres/Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to see if I already have an item in the database. However I can't figure out how to select the name with an apostrophe(') in them.

I have tried using adapt, %s (which does not work at all). :item syntax does not work either.

The below select will result in

```
Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "s"
LINE 1: select * from items where name = 'Akunda's Bite'

# CODE
str_sql = text(f"select * from items where name = '{item_name}'")

results = self.conn.execute(str_sql).fetchone()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using (f-) string formatting, use the DB-API's [parameter substitution method](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries):

```
str_sql = text("select * from items where name = %s;")
results = self.conn.execute(str_sql, (item_name,)).fetchone()
```

Note that the value(s) must be passed as a *sequence*; specifically a `tuple` or a `list`.  A string is a sequence, but each character in the string will be interpreted as a distinct value for the query, which will result in

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

being raised.

Comment: This does not need a tuple. str_sql = "select * from items where name = %s"

        results = self.conn.execute(str_sql, item_name).fetchone()

Comment: Then ```item_name``` must be a tuple or list.